# How to detect tap only on cells not on whole collection view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have `collectionView` in my app. I have a requirement that I should be able to both double & single tap on cells to perform diffrent operations. To make it possible both double & single tap gesture on the `collectionView` I have added both the gesture on collection view & got the location by below code.

```
-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
  if([arr_userAlbums count]>0)
  {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
      return;
    }
    p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collection_view];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collection_view indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];

    celltTapped_index_path=indexPath;
  }
}

-(void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
  if([arr_userAlbums count]>0)
  {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
      return;
    }
    p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collection_view];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collection_view indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];

    celltTapped_index_path=indexPath;
  }
}
```

But in this case the whole screen even where cells are not visible it is accepting the double tap & single tap. I want to detect single & double tap only on cells not the whole collection view.

Comment: you could add a different `tapGestureRecognizer` to each cell.

Comment: Deepak Kumar please try my coding it is working fine.Incase If you want sample coding, i will send you.

Comment: Deepak Kumar you can use my new answer.

Comment: Deepak Kumar please tick and up vote my answer because others copied my answer and posted here.Before they do like this,tick and up vote my answer.It works perfectly.

Comment: but i am not able to remove the tap getsure on click of button

Comment: I have a nav bar button on click of that i want to remove the gestures which i have added.I want to remove the gesture from cells

Comment: But what have you asked the question.Don't fool us.It is very stupid-able.

Comment: I am not fooling your answer does not fit into my app.So you should be having a solution for that as well

Comment: In your question you mentioned only the single and double tap on specific cells.You have not mentioned any other things.

Comment: Ok if you don't want to help then it's fine.I can accept your answert for given question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";
 customCell *cell = (customCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

 cell.img_Collection.image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.lbl_Collection.text = [lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 cell.tag = indexPath.row;

 UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
 singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
 singleTap.delaysTouchesEnded = YES;

 UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
 doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;


 [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];

 [cell addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
 [cell addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

 return cell;
}



-(void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
   NSLog(@"The single tap happened for %ld th index",recognizer.view.tag);
}


-(void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
  NSLog(@"The Double tap happened for %ld th index",recognizer.view.tag);
}
```

Comment: If you want sample i send u right now.Don't worry.I tried this and it works out well.

Answer (score -1):

you can get tapped View by using hitTest Method like this

```
UIView *tappedView = [self hitTest:yourLocation forEvents:nil];
```

This will return you the view which is tapped
 Check this with if condition like this

```
if(tappedView == Imageview)
{
    // do this
}
else if(tappedView == CollectionViewCell)
{
    // do this
}
```